# Preference fragment tab adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences

I want to build a preference tab for my app but since I have other tabs extending from a regular fragment, I have an incompatible types error, as a PreferenceFragment cannot be converted to Fragment.

Here is my Tab Fragment Adapter :

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Tab1Discover tab1 = new Tab1Discover();
            return tab1;
        case 1:
            Tab2Planning tab2 = new Tab2Planning();
            return tab2;
        case 2:
            Tab3Favorites tab3 = new Tab3Favorites();
            return tab3;
        case 3:
            Tab4Messages tab4 = new Tab4Messages();
            return tab4;
        case 4 :
            /*Tab5Profile tab5 = new Tab5Profile();
            return tab5;*/
            return new PreferenceFragment() {
                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
                }
            };
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are incompatible types, the problem is - your fragments inherited from support.v4.app.Fragment, but PreferenceFragment inherited from android.app.Fragment.

There are two ways you could deal with it:

1. Inherit all your fragments from android.app.Fragment
2. Reimplement PreferenceFragment by taken it source code from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.java) for example and inherit it from support.v4.app.Fragment