# What is the Android equivalent of a UITableView as used in this app I'm porting?

Tags: android, ios, uitableview, listview, android-fragments

I'm trying to port an iOS app to Android. I'm an Android noob, but I'm quite experienced in iOS. Here is a screenshot of my app.

[image]

The `UITableView` has custom cell types: Switch cells, tap to toggle the switch on and off. Multi-value cells: tap to expand a `UIPickerView`. My iOS app also has a tab bar for more screens.

So I started with the default `TabLayout` template in Android Studio, and made it to show three different fragments.

I then moved on to making the main interface. That was when the `PreferenceFragment` popped up in my searches, and seemed like a very good idea – my iOS app has a relatively complicated architecture to keep track of the state, and the `PreferenceFragment` promised to take care of that transparently, so I was in.

However, the `TabLayout` [does not seem to like `PreferenceFragments`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33328177/preference-fragment-tab-adapter) because they are not the same as *compat* fragments (did I get that right?). Anyway, the linked question suggests a couple of solutions that I'd rather not follow (re-invent the wheel? Seriously?).

Reading around, people suggest I might get away with a `PreferenceActivity` instead, but I really liked the idea of fragments, mostly because I want my app to scale to tablet and have a "different" UI, with the two different lists of parameters showing up side by side – a job for fragments, right?

Now, the best I can figure is to go back to `RecyclerView`s, so my question is: is that it? And if so, do `RecyclerView`s support simultaneous different types of cells like `UITableView`s do? I should also say that I don't particularly care for Android <5.0, if that helps…

Any other hints or pointers for me to follow when porting iOS apps to Android?

Comment: Your edits removed all the context, but hey, they are shorter…

Comment: The difference between "I'm porting from X to Y" and "I'm programming for Y" is substantial, though, in particular with the "I'm a noob at Y" qualification. It's not just saying "I don't know how to Y" but "please help me translate my pre-existing knowledge between X and Y". Otherwise one might just assume that I don't know Y and give me an irrelevant and long-winded lecture on Y that does not take advantage of my pre-existing knowledge. If I were OK with that, there are plenty of tutorials out there. If I'm here, it means that I did not find what I needed in those tutorials.

Comment: > And I probably have the answer as an ios->android type like you! — Maybe just try and answer, then? I honestly think my question is clear enough. If you did not understand, you could have asked for clarification, not go all over my question and replace it with what you thought I was asking. Not just unhelpful, but also rude and presumptuous.

Comment: The raison d'etre of the site is that one asks a question and others answer if they can. Full stop. I've had edited questions in the past, and I've been perfectly happy with all those edits, because they improved my questions. Instead, you not only edited removing all context, but also commented saying how I don't know how to ask questions, and you don't understand what I'm asking. I mean, come on…

Comment: So, you don't understand my question, you misuse French, and you go all the way to say that you might even be able to answer my question… and yet do not to that! Well, I don't know what you are still doing here. I'm keeping parts of your edits because I think they make my question clearer, but I am just as free to question your judgement that changing an explanation of the circumstances to literally just "An iOS app…" is an improvement in clarity. Quite frankly, that was butchering clarity.

Comment: There is a lot going on in this question, perhaps only some of which I have limited experience. First, TabLayout should work fine with Fragments. In my own app, I used this as a template:
http://www.truiton.com/2015/06/android-tabs-example-fragments-viewpager/

Comment: However, as you say, there is some kind of type mismatch with PreferenceFragment. Whatever suggestion or tutorial I got it from I don't remember, but my PreferenceFragment is simply wrapped by a normal AppCompatActivity that replaces the screen, remaining separate from the tab structure.

Comment: @Graham Thanks, I might just do that. I might just be still a bit confused about activities. In the end, when moving to the side-by-side arrangement, I would have to have the two fragments wrapped up in either a super-fragment or an activity anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The reason `TabLayout` does not seem to like a [`PreferenceFragment`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) is because `PreferenceFragment` extends `android.app.Fragment` not `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (you did get that right), which the `TabLayout` (in reality, the `FragmentPagerAdapter`) expects.

If you want the functionality of a `PreferenceFragment` to be paired with other app-compat widgets, import the [v7 Preference Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7-preference):

```
compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.2.1'
```

Then you can extend [`android.support.v7.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.html), which itself extends from `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.